# How to run program of osg with qt for android?

Tags: android, qt, openscenegraph

I have installed qt for android on my windows system,now I want to run a program with osg(openscenegraph) on android device via qt,Please tell me step by step procedure as I have searched almost all links for above problem but there is no support available.
Please if anyone know answer me soon.I really need help regarding this.

Thanks and Regards
Siddharth Agarwal

Comment: What do you mean by running a program osg on android device via Qt ? What did  you try ? Do you have any error messages ?

Comment: Hi Martinad,.... Actually I have made an app in C++ using Qt and I have used OSG libraries because I had done some coding using OSG as well.The app works fine on windows...but now I want to run the same app on Android as Qt supports cross platform so I am unable to configure it to run on android because my app uses OSG which is a 3rd party library ....so any help regarding above problem statement is highly apperciated..Thanks!

Comment: Nobody answers here..sad!!!

Comment: Unclear questions are often ignored on stackoverflow. If you want to use OSG lib on Android, you have to cross compile it. I don't seek if it's compatbile or not.